# Why is my addStar() function not working if i decide to run it again for the second time?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am into JavaScript and while attempting a project that will be powered by JavaScript I got stuck.

This project is supposed to work like a contact Application that works on a mobile phone with capabilities to add a contact, add the contact to favourite, edit the contact, search, change the theme of the application and delete the contact.

**I have reached the point where you can add a contact but when i created the functionality to add the contact to favourite- If i add a contact to the `favArray` and remove it from the `favArray` and I change my mind and I try to add it back to the `favArray` it will not work(this i do by clicking the star button on the page that appears when you click the created contact) .** I have tried debugging this but it just seems to me that i have been stuck.

I am unable to add a saved contact to the `favArray`again after i have added it to the `favArray` and removed it from the `favArray`- Humbly, from my point of view, I think the problem is coming from the `addStar()` function.

```js
// META CAPABILITIES TO ADD TO FAVOURITES; EDIT THE CONTACT; AND DELETE THE CONTACT

const star = document.querySelector('.star');
star.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-sharp fa-regular fa-star"></i>';
// const edit = document.querySelector('.edit');
// const removeCon = document.querySelector('.delete');
    
function addStar(){
    starClicked = true;
    if (star.innerHTML === '<i class="fa-sharp fa-regular fa-star"></i>') {
        favArray.push(currentContact);
        starClicked = false;
        star.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>';
    } else  if (favArray.includes(currentContact) && star.innerHTML === '<i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>') {
        const index = favArray.indexOf(currentContact);
        favArray.splice(index, 1);
        star.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>';
    }
}      
star.addEventListener('click', addStar);
```

I expected my console to give me a particular error so I checked the console but to my dismay, there was no error.

I tried building the `addStar()` function from scratch but it did not work. After doing this i expected that whenever i click the star on the description page it should work but it was adding the contact to the `favArray` and if i click the star it will remove it from `favArray` and after i have removed it, if i decide to add it back to the `favArray` by clicking the star it will not work.

And as suggested by Members of this great community I also tried putting the **`addStar()`** function and the **`doc()`** function outside the loop that loops through the entire contactArray.
Also I tried adding breakpoints and checking if it enters the correct branch then I realised that after adding it to the `favArray` for the first time and I remove it from the `favArray` and i decide not to close the description page and still change my mind and try to add it back to the `favArray`-** the `addStar()` function will not run until i close the description page.**
I have also tried asking ChatGpt about it but it gave me a code that introduced more bugs and I am a person that likes implementing what i understand.

- [The code on github](https://github.com/tolu1123/contactApplication.git)
- [The actual page](https://contact-application-three.vercel.app)
- [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/tolu1123/pen/abRxYmL) (you will not be able to see the addContact page)

Comment: Where is that `i` coming from? Set a breakpoint in your eventhandler and check 1) if it even enters the correct branch  2) what `contactArray[i]` is

Comment: You have a loop `for (let i = 0; i < contactArray.length; i++) {`, within that loop you have a function `function doc() {` and within it you have `function addStar() {`.  This is a wrong and very error-prone structure. You need to extract all these functions from each other and the loop and get rid of unnecessary dependency from the loop. Also, you need to keep the state of your app in a dedicated variable instead of relying on global `i`. Once you open a contact for view, save it into a var `currentContact` and then just add/remove it from `favArray`.

Comment: @derpirscher
 The `i`  is comng from the loop parameters- for `(let i = 0; i < contactArray.length; i++) {`, I have added a breakpoint and it is entering the correct branch, it also gives the value of `contactArray[i];` In summary everything runs well. Thank you Great Hunter.

Comment: Thank you @RAllen for your suggestion and your correction, I did not think of that, but i will try it and get back to you. But i did not understand the lines where you said- " You need to extract all these functions from each other and the loop and get rid of unnecessary dependency from the loop. Also, you need to keep the state of your app in a dedicated variable instead of relying on global i." Seriously it is better having to be in a community than be a lone developer. Thank you Sir RAllen.

Comment: @Dramatic_Monk810 see my answer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the function `updateContacts` you have a loop that goes through all the contacts:

```
function updateContactList() {
  ...
  for (let i = 0; i < contactArray.length; i++) {
```

Later in the code, within the same loop, you use this `i` within the `addStar` function to get the contact with a specific index:

```
function addStar() {
  ...
  const index = favArray.indexOf(contactArray[i]);
  ...
}
```

After that, you add a `click` handler for the `star` icon:

```
star.addEventListener('click', addStar);
```

Now let's imagine how this work.
In every iteration of the loop, you kind of create a new instance of `addStar` with a specific `i` and attach it to the **same single star icon.**

The result is that when you click the star icon, all `addStar` functions for all contacts will be executed.

You can easily test this by adding `console.log('addStar', i);` as a very first line within the `addStar()` function, create 3 contacts, open any of them, and star it. Open the console and check what you see.

Now let's think about how to fix this problem.

I would recommend you to read a bit about Model-View-Controller concept to get an idea of `model` (aka state) and `view` (its visual re-presentation). In your code, everything is mixed all together, and it makes it hard to manage a `model` and a `view` in a structured way. Ideally, you should be able to completely separate the code that modifies HTML from the code that manages the list of contacts as an array of objects (your model).

What you need to do now with the current approach.

You need to move the `addStar` and `viewContact` (called `doc`) function out of the loop. You don't need to make a copy of these functions for each contact. For these functions to work, you need to know the `currentContact` the user `clicked`. In the loop itself, you only create contacts and attach a click handler. That click handler should set `currentContact` to the contact clicked and call `viewContact`. Within `viewContact` user will be able to click the `star` icon, and `addStar` will use the `currentContact` global variable to add or remove its value from favorites.

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Overall Your answer was very helpful to me. Though I had the premonition that the console would spit out an error at me, I still went on to do`console.log('addStar', i);` and when i did it returned an error saying '`i` was not defined'.  Meanwhile the `addStar()` functionability improved when i moved the `doc()` and the `addStar()` out of the loop.  Improved is what i mean by saying i can now add a contact to the favArray and it would not add the others to the favArray, also another area of improvement is that i can now add as many contact i have to the favArray.

Comment: The only downside is that after I add a contact to favourite in the favArray and i remove it fom the favArray I would not be able to add to favArray again till i close the view contact page (aboutMe page). It is only when i close it and open it again and i then click the star button to add it to favourite that is when it will work.

Comment: Now, when your `favArray` is a source of truth about whether the contact is starred, you no longer need to check `if (star.innerHTML === '<i class="fa-sharp fa-regular fa-star"></i>')` because now, your favorites are data-driven! All that you need is to check `if (!favArray.includes(currentContact)) {` and `favArray.push(currentContact);` if `true` or `favArray.splice(index, 1);`if `false`. Updating `star.innerHTML` with a solid or regular star should be done in `updateStar()` (a new func) by checking `if (avArray.includes(currentContact))`. You should never check HTML to identify the state.

Comment: We did quite a lot of work together, and you've made a huge progress! Do not forget to format your code to make it more readable and convenient to work with. Please do not forget to mark my answer as a solution if it is helpful for you. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much, your solution has been really helpful. I will try to make it more readable and convenient to work with.    Now I can add a contact to favourite as much as possible.